# how flash builder whitelist cross domain security sandbox

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain, flash-builder

I am writing a program to send out a HTTP GET request to a server that I don't have privilege access to.

If the program is running inside my flash builder workspace, then everything is working fine.

Now when I copy and paste the program outside the flash builder workspace flash player throws a security error.

I know it's a cross domain security issue, I wonder why within the flash builder workspace it's working and otherwise it's not. If I want to release the program what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't place a crossdomain.xml on that server an option is to whip out a quick server-side script in the language you prefer and can use on the server hosting your swf.

The server-side script should copy/cache the GET result on the server hosting the swf so you can access the data without security sandbox restrictions.

Rather than something like this:

```
Server A->SWF->GET->SERVER B
```

you would do something like this:

```
SWF->SERVER A->SCRIPT GET->SERVER B->SCRIPT GET RESULT->SWF
```

It's not ideal(you'd use a crossdomain file), but should do the trick

Comment: I noticed that too. I am still working on copying the session over to the proxy. I wonder why the flash builder workspace can work. Is there some way to make it work like that?